# PHP Syntax double square brackets

Tags: php, syntax

I am parsing through some code and having trouble understanding a snippet

```
$htmlinputs = array();

$htmlinputs['src']['available'] = array();
```

I understand that an array is made by the var name of "htmlinputs" but I am confused about the second line.

Is it making a second array at the index of 'src' and 'available'? this is the first time 'src' and 'available' are mentioned at all in the code.

Comment: It is making a multidimensional array.

Comment: if there is no code between the first and second line, the first one is not necessary.  the second line is defining $htmlinputs as a multidimentional array.  if there is other code between those two lines, it's possible that $htmlinputs is first used as a single dimension array and then redefined at the second line... and that's not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The double brackets indicates a [multi-dimensional array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp).  It's an array of one or more arrays.
In the example you've given

```
$htmlinputs['src']['available'] = array();
```

If 'src' and 'available' have not been previously mentioned in the code, the indices are being created with that statement.  It's possible it's superfluous and can be combined with the actual value assignment, or perhaps this is creating the indices due for scope reasons.

Comment: i updated my explanation.  that statement is creating them.

Comment: edit: thanks for responding so quickly, would I be able to access the arrays indices like normal (ie $htmlinputs[0][0] or would I have to have the 'key' to access the innermost array?)

Comment: $htmlinputs[0][0] will give you an undefined offset.  var_dump($htmlinputs) will show you the structure.  then try var_dump($htmlinputs[0][0] to see undefined offset).  these are string indexes, as opposed to integer indexes.